# Overload resolution failed when trying to obtain data from access

Tags: vb.net

I am coding a POS and I am stuck when I try to view specific data from the access database. Every time I try I get this error:

> Error  1   Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'New' is most specific for these arguments:
>
> 'Public Sub New(name As String, dataSourceValue As System.Collections.IEnumerable)': Not most specific.
>
> 'Public Sub New(name As String, dataSourceValue As System.Data.DataTable)': Not most specific.
>
> C:\Users\EMIL\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\P.O.S\FrmMain.vb   402 17  AdvanceLoginForm

Please can anyone show me whats wrong with my code

```
Private Sub Button4_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
    If ComboBox1.Text = "Total Profit for all time" Then
        Dim TA As New POSDSTableAdapters.TotalProfitForAllTimeTableAdapter
        Dim TmpDS As New POSDS
        TA.Fill(TmpDS.TotalProfitForAllTime)

        'clear previous datasource
        RV.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear()

        'create new datasource
        Dim RDS As New Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource("POSDS_TotalProfitForAllTime.rdlc", TmpDS.TotalProfitForAllTime)

        RV.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(RDS)
        RV.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "POS.TotalProfitForAllTime.rdlc"
        RV.RefreshReport()
    ElseIf ComboBox1.Text = "Total Profit between two dates" Then
        Dim TA As New POSDSTableAdapters.TotalProfitForAllTimeTableAdapter
        Dim TmpDS As New POSDS

        TA.FillByFilteringBetweenTwoDates(TmpDS.TotalProfitForAllTime, DateTimePicker1.Value, DateTimePicker2.Value)

        'clear previous datasource
        RV.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear()

        'create new datasource 
        Dim RDS As New Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource("POSDS_TotalProfitForAllTime.rdlc", TmpDS.TotalProfitForAllTime)

        RV.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(RDS)
        RV.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "POS.TotalProfitBetweenTwoDates.rdlc"
        RV.RefreshReport()
    End If
End sub
```

The error is at:

```
Dim RDS As New Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource("POSDS_TotalProfitForAllTime.rdlc", TmpDS.TotalProfitForAllTime)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cast the strongly typed `DataTable` to `DataTable` to resolve this ambiguity issue:

```
Dim table As DataTable = DirectCast(TmpDS.TotalProfitForAllTime, DataTable)
Dim RDS As New Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource("POSDS_TotalProfitForAllTime.rdlc", table)
```

The problem is that in 2010 there are [two methods which are possible](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reporting.winforms.reportdatasource.reportdatasource(v=vs.100).aspx), one that takes a `DataTable` and one that takes an `IEnumerable`. A strongly typed `DataTable` inherits from [`TypedTableBase(Of T)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Bb358258(v=vs.110).aspx) which inherits from/implements:

- `DataTable`,
- `IEnumerable(Of T)`,
- `IEnumerable`

That's why the compiler doesn't know which contsructor it should use. He could choose both overloads, so you need to tell the compiler explicitly what you want.

Comment: Then you might want to accept the answer. You're welcome